# Sum of two numbers is equal to hcf +lcm

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let m and n be positive integers such that

lcm[m,n]+gcd[m,n]=m+n

Prove that one of the numbers must be divisible by the other.

I tried it by taking m>n and then taking the factors of n which are not in the gcd and tried to show that it also divides m but failed.

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Note that $lcm (m,n) \times \gcd(m,n)=mn$.

If for four real numbers $a+b=c+d$, $ab=cd$, this implies that $a=c, b=d$ or $a=d, b=c$ since they are both two roots to the quadratic equation $x^2-(c+d)x+cd$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $LCM(m,n)=l$. It is known that
$$LCM(m,n)\times GCD(m,n)=m\times n$$
$$GCD(m,n)=\frac{mn}{l}$$
Thus,
$$l+\frac{mn}l=m+n$$
$$l^2+mn=lm+ln$$
$$l^2-lm-ln+mn=0$$
$$(l-m)(l-n)=0$$
$$l=m \text{ or } l=n$$
Without loss of generality, let $l=m$. By definition of $LCM$, $m=nk$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

As lcm$[m,n]+$gcd$[m,n]=m+n$

and we know  lcm$[m,n]\cdot$gcd$[m,n]=m\cdot n$

lcm$[m,n]=$max$(m,n)$

gcd$[m,n]=$min$(m,n)$